# Is it ok to return default argument's value by const reference?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, object-lifetime, default-arguments, reference-binding

Is it ok to return default argument's value by const reference like in the examples below:

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff76e060a007723b

```
#include <string>

const std::string& foo(const std::string& s = std::string(""))
{
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    const std::string& s1 = foo();
    std::string s2 = foo();

    const std::string& s3 = foo("s");
    std::string s4 = foo("s");
}
```

Comment: Simple test: replace `std::string` with a class of your own so you can track construction and destruction.

Comment: @user4581301 If the sequence is correct it wouldn't prove that the construct is ok though.

Comment: @user4581301 "It appeared to work when I tried it" is the absolute worst thing about undefined behavior

Comment: It should be noted that the question is a tidbit misleading in its wording. You're not returning a default argument's value by const reference, but you are returning a const reference to a const reference (... to a default argument).

Comment: @HerrJoebob Agree with the statement 100%, but not the context you're using it in. The way I read it this question resolves to "When is object's lifetime over?" figuring out when the destructor is called is a good way to do that. For an Automatic variable the destructor should be called right on time or you've got big problems.

Comment: @user4581301 There's your problem, it's not an automatic variable - it's a *temporary* and its lifetime is not defined enough to be subject to 'try and see what happens' testing. In any case 'try and see' shouldn't be encouraged.

Comment: @HerrJoebob: it is defined. Check Brian's answer

Answer (score 18):

In your code, both `s1` and `s3` are dangling references. `s2` and `s4` are ok.

In the first call, the temporary empty `std::string` object created from the default argument will be created in the context of the expression containing the call. Therefore, it will die at the end of the definition of `s1`, which leaves `s1` dangling.

In the second call, the temporary `std::string` object is used to initialize `s2`, then it dies.

In the third call, the string literal `"s"` is used to create a temporary `std::string` object and that also dies at the end of the definition of `s3`, leaving `s3` dangling.

In the fourth call, the temporary `std::string` object with value `"s"` is used to initialize `s4` and then it dies.

See C++17 [class.temporary]/6.1

> A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call (8.2.2) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.

Comment: The interesting part of the answer is the assertion that the default argument will be created in the caller's context. That seems to be supported by Guillaume's standard quote.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica See [expr.call]/4, "... The initialization and destruction of each parameter occurs within the context of the calling function. ..."

Answer (score 8):

It is [not safe](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary):

> In general, the lifetime of a temporary cannot be further extended by
>   "passing it on": a second reference, initialized from the reference to
>   which the temporary was bound, does not affect its lifetime.

Comment: So do you think `std::string s2 = foo();` is valid (after all, no reference is passed on explicitly)?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica that one is safe as new object will be constructed. My answer is merely about lifetime expansion. The other two answers already covered everything. I wouldn't repeat in mine.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you do with the string afterwards.

If your question is *is my code correct?* then yes is it.

From [[dcl.fct.default]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.default#2.example-1)

> [ *Example*: The declaration
>
> ```
> void point(int = 3, int = 4);
> ```
>
> declares a function that can be called with zero, one, or two
>   arguments of type int. It can be called in any of these ways:
>
> ```
> point(1,2);  point(1);  point();
> ```
>
> The last two calls are equivalent to `point(1,4)` and `point(3,4)`,
>   respectively. — *end example*]

So your code is effectively equivalent to:

```
const std::string& s1 = foo(std::string(""));
std::string s2 = foo(std::string(""));
```

All your code is correct, but there is no reference lifetime extension in any of these cases, since the return type is a reference.

Since you call a function with a temporary, the lifetime of the returned string won't extend the statement.

```
const std::string& s1 = foo(std::string("")); // okay

s1; // not okay, s1 is dead. s1 is the temporary.
```

Your example with `s2` is okay since you copy (or move) from the temporary before the end of the satement. `s3` has the same problem than `s1`.